# Printing from Datecs FML 10KL

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, serial-port, compact-framework

I am using .NET CF and my task is to print fiscal and non-fiscal receipt.
So I need to connect to the FML 10 KL via bluetooth.
I am using **SerialPort** to do this, but after sending commands nothing happens.
I tried sending the commands like this :

```
    byte[] buf = new byte[218];
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(inPort.BaseStream))
    {
       writer.Write(buf);
       //inPort.NewLine = "\n";
       //var msg = inPort.ReadLine();
    }
```

I populate "buf" with my command.
After that I try to read the responce but everytime I get timeout.Also I tried to "write" with text and not byte array, but I get the same result.
If anyone can give me some advice that would be great.

Comment: I would recommend using the `Write` with text from your `SerialPort` class as you suggested you tried.  But you need to make sure your `SerialPort` is setup correctly.  Check the following settings: the `BaudRate`, `DataBits`, `Parity`, `PortName`, and `StopBits`.

Answer (score 0):

Most serial devices including Bluetooth SPP and Socket controlled devices do not support Unicode. If you have a string, you need to use Encoding ASCII (or UTF8) getBytes to get a byte arry suitable for the serial or direct socket connection. If you do not care for this, you may get a byte sequence of {0x00, 0x41} (Unicode) for an 'A' instead of the needed {0x41} only.

If you try to print something, verify that the code you send is valid by writing the data to a file and send the file as it is using a terminal application (former HyperTerminal).

Most printers support a Dump mode. Verify that the code you build is transmitted un-altered to the printer by using the dump mode and compare with the validated code that you used to print.

The Operating System and the target device may use a buffer. Ensure the buffer is flushed and then close the Stream before disconnecting.

With the Serial Port class ensure the device and the class use the same parameters, ie both 8Bit etc. For Bluetooth SPP the baud rate is adopted, you may use 115200 or 57600 without failing.

I found a Class that supports the Datecs Fiscal Printing Protocol: https://github.com/wqweto/UcsFiscalPrinters/blob/master/Samples/Demo1/Program.cs you should probably use this or look at how the class does print on the Datecs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.It was the connection to the mobile printer.
I am connecting and writing like this:

> SerialPort inport = new SerialPort("COM5", 115200, Parity.None, 8,
>   StopBits.One);
>   inport.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
>   Thread.Sleep(1000);

I need to use Thread.Sleep because the buffer is getting full and some of data is not getting printed.